# MySQL: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a MySQL database, have the following 3 tables:

**map_range**
[image]

**map_location (join table)**
[image]

**location**
[image]

I am trying to add some foreign keys.

```
    ALTER TABLE `www`.`map_location` 
ALTER TABLE `www`.`map_location` 
ADD INDEX `fk_map_location_indx` (`LOC_ID` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `www`.`map_location` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_map_loc_map`
  FOREIGN KEY (`MAP_ID`)
  REFERENCES `www`.`map_location` (`MAP_ID`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_map_loc_location`
  FOREIGN KEY (`LOC_ID`)
  REFERENCES `www`.`location` (`ID`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

But I get the following error:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
    ERROR 1025: Error on rename of '.\www\#sql-ea0_2b8' to '.\www\map_location' (errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)
    SQL Statement:
    ALTER TABLE `www`.`map_location` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_map_loc_map`
      FOREIGN KEY (`MAP_ID`)
      REFERENCES `www`.`map_location` (`MAP_ID`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_map_loc_location`
      FOREIGN KEY (`LOC_ID`)
      REFERENCES `www`.`location` (`ID`)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

[image]

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: what is `www`.`map_location` . ? Is it another table?

Comment: @Jagrati 'www' is the schema name. I am using MySQL Workbench, and this is the SQL generated by it.

Comment: @Jagrati yes it is a table pictured above. OP what is your mysql version? I am assuming the duplicated alter table line is just a copy paste error? looks like you are trying to reference map_id to itself

Comment: you are altering map_location table, and generating reference to map_location only : `ALTER TABLE www.map_location ADD CONSTRAINT fk_map_loc_map FOREIGN KEY (MAP_ID) REFERENCES www.map_location (MAP_ID) `. why?

Comment: @khuderm, thank you!  That was my mistake, map_location was referencing itself. It should be referencing another table (map_range).  Appreciate the help. It works now if I reference the correct table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are self-refferencing the same table and colum.
did you mean to `location` and not `map_location`?

```
ALTER TABLE `www`.`map_location`
ADD CONSTRAINT... FOREIGN KEY (`MAP_ID`)
REFERENCES `www`.`map_location` (`MAP_ID`)
```